How to add react-native VPN connection to Socks5/VLess protocols
Can anyone give me an example for how to add Socks5/VLess connection in my react-native application?
I have an VPN application, with button "Connect" but can't find any info about how to make connections in react-native.
My current const to make connections:
const connectVPN = async () => {
        // If already connected, reset timer
        if (isConnected) {
            resetTimer();
            return;
        }

        setConnecting(true);
        // Retry logic up to maxAttempts
        for (let i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/credentials');
                if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Failed to get credentials");
                const data = await res.json();
                const {username, password} = data;
                const success = true;

                if (success) {
                    setIsConnected(true);
                    setConnectionAttempts(0);
                    setConnecting(false);
                    resetTimer();
                    startTimer();
                    return;
                } else {
                    throw new Error("VPN connect failed");
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                setConnectionAttempts(i + 1);
            }
        }
        setConnecting(false);
        alert(t('error'));
    };

After the credentials step I need to set connection to VPNServer using Socks5 or VLess protocols
